# How to implement auto scroll top/bottom in SectionList in React Native?

Tags: react-native

In my current project, I have a drag & drop feature in SectionList. For convenience, i will scroll SectionList to top/down automatically scroll when the user dragging item at top or bottom screen.

Because the `scrollTo` function not public in SectionList, so, I archive it like that.

1. requestAnimationFrame
2. scroll SectionList by a delta distance (ex: 5 pixel)

```
const listRef =
      this._sectionList._wrapperListRef &&
      this._sectionList._wrapperListRef.getListRef();
    if (listRef) {
      listRef.scrollToOffset({offset, animated: false});
    }
```

It's work perfectly on iOS, but in Android, the section header be laggy when scroll top/down. See below video for details.

I has searched in Google, dive into the react-native ScrollView.js code, and try to print MessageSpy message. But I can not find what wrong code.

Has anyone had any idea about my case?

I'd followed in this article and print debug. But it's too hard for me to fully understanding how to found out the problem is.

Article link:
https://medium.com/@jondot/debugging-react-native-performance-snoopy-and-the-messagequeue-fe014cd047ac

Below is my reproduce code. Hope it useful.

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {Text, View, SectionList} from 'react-native';

export class Foo extends PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    let offset = 5;
    let step = 5;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        offset += step;
        if (offset >= 300 || offset <= 0) {
          step = step * -1;
        }
        this.scrollToOffset(offset, false);
      }, 150);
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }

  scrollToOffset = (offset, animated) => {
    const listRef =
      this._flatList._wrapperListRef &&
      this._flatList._wrapperListRef.getListRef();
    if (listRef) {
      listRef.scrollToOffset({offset, animated});
}
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
        <SectionList
          ref={ref => (this._flatList = ref)}
          renderItem={({item, index, section}) => (
            <View style={{height: 150, padding: 8}}>
              <Text key={index}>{item}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  height: 50,
                  backgroundColor: 'white',
                }}>
                {title}
              </Text>
          )}
          sections={[
            {
              title: 'Title1',
              data: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6'],
            }
          ]}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
          stickySectionHeadersEnabled
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Foo;
```

Video bug demo.
https://youtu.be/sOC-7H4t6NM

Comment: Anybody can help me?